# returned values cannot be accessed outside react map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mapping an array to create a array with the structure of my liking. I've done it as follows

```
    let bookingsArr = [];
    providers.map((item,key)=>{
        item.bookings.map((booking,key)=>{
            bookingsArr.push({"title":item.title,"seeker":booking.seekerId,"status":booking.status,"imageUrl":item.imageUrl});
            console.log("this gets printed",bookingsArr);
        })
    })

    console.log("this does not get printed",bookingsArr);
```

Here i have console logged the `bookingsArr` but for some reason it will not get printed in my terminal. The code doesn't run after the map. But if i console log `bookingArr` inside the map function i can see the console log in my terminal. I need to use `bookingArr` outside the map function. What's causing the issue here?

Full function

```
export const loadBookings = async () => {
    const providersSnapshot = await firebase.database().ref('Clothvalues').once('value');
    const providers = providersSnapshot && providersSnapshot.val();

    if (!providers) {
        return undefined;
    }
    let bookingsArr = [];
    providers.map((item,key)=>{
        item.bookings.map((booking,key)=>{
            bookingsArr.push({"title":item.title,"seeker":booking.seekerId,"status":booking.status,"imageUrl":item.imageUrl});
            console.log("this gets printed",bookingArr);
        })
    })
    console.log("this does not get printed",bookingArr);

    return bookingsArr;
};
```

So basically i want `loadBookings` function to return my array.

Comment: Could you provide a full code of this or an online demo? Which may help others to catch up with the problem you are facing quickly.

Comment: i have posted the full function now.

Comment: It seems you have the same variable name about the two `key`

Comment: Could you provide some data to test this on?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Hooks to return the bookingsArr

```
function loadBookings() {
    const [bookingsArr, setbookingsArr] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      firebase.database().ref('Clothvalues').once('value').then((providers)=>{
        if (!providers.val()) {
            return undefined;
        }else{
            providers.map((item,key)=>{
                item.bookings.map((booking,key)=>{
                    setbookingsArr(bookingArr => [...bookingArr, {"title":item.title,"seeker":booking.seekerId,"status":booking.status,"imageUrl":item.imageUrl}]);
                })
            })
        }
      })
  });

  return bookingsArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map isn't intended to be used in this way - it is supposed to return an array and you aren't returning anything in it's callback at all. You should use a `reduce`, to turn the nested arrays into a flat one and a `map` to modify the objects inside the nested arrays

```
    let bookingsArr = providers.reduce((wholeArray, item)=> ([
        ...wholeArray,
        ...item.bookings.map((booking) => ({
            "title": item.title, 
            "seeker": booking.seekerId, 
            "status": booking.status, 
            "imageUrl": item.imageUrl
        }))
    ]), [])
```

Comment: still i cannot get bookingsArr to print

Comment: Any errors? I was making some changes, because I missed a couple things, so you might have tried an old version

Comment: No errors. even the way i've done is working. Issue is accessing the value outside the map function.

Comment: It's hard to tell why it's not working without any data

Answer (score 0):

Basically I guess the error is because of spelling mistake.

you have create the `let bookingsArr = [];`

But in console log you are using `bookingArr`

Comment: That was a mistake i've done when posting the question. In my function it's correctly put